# using array as key to loop through objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning JavaScript and have spent a good deal of time practicing looping through arrays and arrays of Objects. I wanted to learn how to use an array as a filter on an array of Objects. I couldn't find any articles that explained how to do this, so I had a go myself using a nested loop. However, I cannot get it to work.

Var catKey[];   is the array holding the data I want to use to filter through var posts[];    , identify which objects have a match in the Property cat: []  and return the title properties. I know I could use array.Filter but I want to be able to do this on the assumption I wont always know the number of items in the catKey array. The use case would be for a situation where I use an event handler that when a link I add is clicked on a Post in WordPress and returns the category Ids, I would then search through the list of Posts to find others that have the same category Ids. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
var catKey = [2, 6];
var posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    cat: [1, 2, 3],
    title: "Hello World"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cat: [5, 6, 7],
    title: "Hello JavaScript"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    cat: [8, 9],
    title: "Hello Arrays!"
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < catKey.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < posts.length[i]; j++) {
    if (catKey[i] === posts[j].cat) {
      document.write(posts[j].title);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `posts[j].cat.indexOf(catKey[i])` here.

Comment: Should *all* values in `catKey` match, or *at least one*?

Comment: will number inside `cat` array always be unique??

Comment: not all values need to match, just at least one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the first entry to match your conditions you can make use of [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

```js
var catKey = [2, 6];
var posts = [
  { id: 1, cat: [1, 2, 3], title: "Hello World" },
  { id: 2, cat: [5, 6, 7], title: "Hello JavaScript" },
  { id: 3, cat: [8, 9], title: "Hello Arrays!" }
];

const resObj = posts
    .find(p => p.cat.some(c => catKey.includes(c)))
    .title;

console.log(resObj)
```

Or to find **all**, use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var catKey = [2, 6];
var posts = [
  { id: 1, cat: [1, 2, 3], title: "Hello World" },
  { id: 2, cat: [5, 6, 7], title: "Hello JavaScript" },
  { id: 3, cat: [8, 9], title: "Hello Arrays!" }
];

const resObjs = posts
    .filter(p => p.cat.some(c => catKey.includes(c)))
    .map(o => o.title);

resObjs.forEach((t) => console.log(t));
```

Comment: Many thanks , it was the second code I was looking for to find them all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I assume `catKey` contains a whitelist of numbers that the nested `cat` array should match, i.e. as long as any value in the `cat` array is found in `catKeys`, you want to keep them.

In that case, you can simply use `.filter()` to iterate through all the posts, and evaluate if there is any intersection between the individual post's `cat` array against the whitelist:

```
var filteredPosts = posts.filter(function(post) {
  return post.cat.filter(function(c) { return catKey.indexOf(c) !== -1; }).length;
});
```

If you want to try and write in ES6, that's also not a problem: and it's even more concise!

```
const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => post.cat.filter(c => catKey.includes(c)).length);
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var catKey = [2, 6];
var posts = [{
    id: 1,
    cat: [1, 2, 3],
    title: "Hello World"
  },
  {


    id: 2,
    cat: [5, 6, 7],
    title: "Hello JavaScript"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    cat: [8, 9],
    title: "Hello Arrays!"
  }
];

var filteredPosts = posts.filter(function(post) {
  return post.cat.filter(function(c) { return catKey.indexOf(c) !== -1; }).length;
});
console.log(filteredPosts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `find` together to check the values in the array with the values in the array of objects. Using `map` the `catKey` array is iterated and for `every element` `find` is used to find that element in the array inside the object inside the array named `post` using the `.includes()` method.

```js
var catKey = [2, 6];
var posts = [{
    id: 1,
    cat: [1, 2, 3],
    title: "Hello World"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cat: [5, 6, 7],
    title: "Hello JavaScript"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    cat: [8, 9],
    title: "Hello Arrays!"
  }];
console.log(catKey.map((e) => posts.find((x) => x.cat.includes(e))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var catKey = [2, 6];
var posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    cat: [1, 2, 3],
    title: "Hello World"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cat: [5, 6, 7],
    title: "Hello JavaScript"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    cat: [8, 9],
    title: "Hello Arrays!"
  }
];

var result = posts.filter(({cat})=>{
  return catKey.filter((key)=>{
     return cat.includes(key)
  }).length > 0
})

console.log(result);
```

### short version

```
posts.filter(({ cat }) => catKey.filter(key => cat.includes(key)).length > 0);
```